# Is the derivative of four-position with respect to an affine parameter for a light ray $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, speed-of-light, calculus

The derivative of four-position with respect to proper time for a light ray is undefined, as light rays move along paths of unchanging proper time. However, would the derivative of four-position with respect to an *affine parameter* for a light ray be:

$$
\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} = \langle 0, c \rangle
$$

as $\frac{dt}{d\lambda}$ would be zero and the rest of the components would be $c$? This is my understanding given that the speed of light is measured to be identical in all reference frames, thus $\frac{dx}{d\lambda}=\frac{dy}{d\lambda}=\frac{dz}{d\lambda}=c$.

Further, if expressed in another coordinate system (e.g. spherical), would $\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$ still be equal to $c$?

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect, as only the *speed* of light is $c$, whereas its components are *not necessarily c*. Thus:

$$
c = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}
$$

The components can be any values $v \leq c$, so long as the square root of their squared values adds up to $c$.